# How to plot a matrix of p-values into a histogram

Tags: matrix, histogram, stata, p-value

I've been searching online for how to plot a histogram of values stored in a matrix, but I am having some trouble doing so. I have created a `forval` loop, where I have stored p-values for 1000 trials of a test, and I want to now plot these p-values on a histogram.

```
/* Loop generating 1000 trials and storing p-values */

mata: pvalue1000 = J(1000,1,.)

forvalues i = 1/1000 {

    clear
    quiet set obs 1000
    gen n = _n
    quiet gen A = runiform()
    quiet ttest A = 0.20

    /*store the mean, in a local variable*/
    local pvalue = r(p)
    gen pval = r(p)

    /*transfer the p-value from the "local" to the matrix */
    mata: pvalue1000[`i',1] = `pvalue'
}

mata: pvalue1000
hist pvalue1000
```

The `hist pvalue1000` in this case, is saying that `pvalue1000` is not found, and when I try to do `hist pval` it just only displays one p-value in the histogram (I am assuming this is because it is outside the loop).

Also note, that the matrix is only storing p-values and all the p-values are stored in a single column (which has 1000 rows). So the matrix is of size 1 column and 1000 rows.

So how would I be able to call a variable with `hist`, where it will plot all of the p-values on this histogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`histogram` expects a variable name, and you are first feeding it a matrix name, so no go there, as matrices and variables are utterly different in Stata.

Conversely, when you then feed it a variable name, your variable `pval` contains only the single and last *P*-value put in it, as all previous incarnations of `pval` were `clear`ed out of the way by your own code. (Putting the histogram command *inside* the loop would have no useful effect here, as at best there is only one *P*-value inside the variable at a time.)

Matrices can be very useful, but they are at best indirect for this purpose.

Presumably your problem is not your real problem. If you have samples of size 1000 from a uniform on (0, 1), then sample means will all be close to 0.5 and *P*-values of a test that the mean is 0.2 will all be practically indistinguishable from 0 and no histogram is interesting or useful. But this code seems to capture your intent:

```
clear 
set obs 1000 
gen A = . 
gen pval = . 

quietly forval i = 1/1000 {
    replace A = runiform()
    ttest A = 0.20
    replace pval = r(p) in `i' 
}

hist pval
```

What's not in this code:

1. Putting results in locals and/or matrices and/or taking them out again is not needed for any purpose. We put them directly into a variable one by one, because that is the result needed.
2. The observation numbers `_n` are not used for anything, so they seem dispensable too, although naturally they may be needed for your real problem.
3. Your comment `store the mean` is not matched by any code that you try.

Note also that talking about `local`s as variables is natural for anyone familiar with other programming languages, but in no sense is it Stata terminology. Locals are local macros, not variables.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation. I am familiar with many programming languages, but I am new to STATA and still figuring out how it works, so your reply was very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Stata's main dataset, matrices that you access using `matrix` command and Mata matrices all live separately and need separate functions to deal with, but you can transfer the data between all three.

In your case, you want to load a Mata matrix into the Stata dataset, which you can do as follows:

```
clear
getmata pvalue1000, double
```

Please not that your p-values are very small, therefore you need to use `double` option. Otherwise you'll get zeros with single precision.

Comment: so I do the getmata pvalue, double after the for loop?

Comment: Yes; if you follow this route then `getmata` follows all else. But note that (numerically) the `double` will be futile as you've already lost precision by putting the values in a `local` first and `double` won't restore that. I'd suggest that (statistically) it's absurd to treat P-values as worthy of double precision.

Comment: @Nick Cox, I havn't looked into what is being tested here - I thought it might be just an example, but if I run the original code then the values collected in mata have double precision, so the macro does not seem to lose precision... If I omit the double option, then all the p-values become zeros when saved to Stata. But I guess you're right and with the actual problem that should not matter.

Comment: Locals hold less precision than scalars. That usually won't bite but it's true; the reason is that putting something into a local macro makes it a string.

Comment: In principle, the string can hold arbitrary precision. I have just tested and locals fully preserve double stata precision. Try generating a double variable with sufficiently many significant digits, saving it to a local and then back to Stata. Then you can assert that the original and the new variables are the same.

Comment: The principle you cite is correct but not the point here. You **can** lose precision assigning to locals, which was my point, although often you may have to look hard to notice and the loss may not be substantively important.  Using scalars is recommended for full precision. This is documented e.g. http://www.stata.com/manuals14/pscalar.pdf

Comment: I did not know. Thanks for the link.